# Laravel 5.4 Passport Personal Token Postman Error Unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel 5.4 Passport for personal tokens. I am trying to use Postman to send a GET request to /api/user. I get my token by sending a GET request to /oauth/personal-access-tokens. From that response I grab what I think is the token then I set up a GET request in Postman like the documents [say](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#passing-the-access-token) Adding Accept => application/json and Authorization => Bearer token. Below is an example:

After logging in, I go to  http://192.168.10.15/oauth/personal-access-tokens in my browser I see the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": "96a494affb39097a562e12e53a32c028cb9b9b481ba4e92ca9fa35df6361583ff9bf3422268345aa",
    "user_id": 1,
    "client_id": 1,
    "name": "API-Token",
    "scopes": [

    ],
    "revoked": false,
    "created_at": "2018-04-28 14:50:02",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-28 14:50:02",
    "expires_at": "2019-04-28 14:50:02",
    "client": {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": null,
      "name": "Test Site Personal Access Client",
      "redirect": "http:\/\/localhost",
      "personal_access_client": true,
      "password_client": false,
      "revoked": false,
      "created_at": "2018-04-28 14:49:18",
      "updated_at": "2018-04-28 14:49:18"
    }
  }
]
```

I'm guessing the token is the id?!?!?  It seems pretty short.

Here is my api.php file:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

I then copy the token from /oauth/personal-access-tokens and use it in my Postman Get request to http://192.168.10.15/api/user below:

[image]

[image]

Am I actually getting the token with the /oauth/personal-access-tokens GET request? and if I am why and I getting the Unauthenticated error?

I have already checked [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-passport-api-unauthenticated-in-postman-using-personal-access-tokens) done the following in AuthServiceProvider.php boot():

```
Passport::routes();

Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addYears(20));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addYears(20));
Passport::pruneRevokedTokens();
```

I am also set up to [Consume My API with Javascript](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript)

I appreciate any and all help!
Please let me know if any other information is need to diagnose this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The "id" is not the the token. To create a valid bearer token, you can refer [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens)